# Pythonから.batファイルや.vbsファイルを実行したい

Tags: python

次の画像のようにファイルが配置されているとします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

各ファイルの中身を以下に示します。

**python_test.py**
python_tes.pyは.batファイルや、.vbsファイルを呼び出します。

```
from os import path
import subprocess

#パターン1 .batファイルを呼び出す
runPath = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'run.bat')
subprocess.Popen(runPath)

#パターン2 .vbsファイルを呼び出す
#vbsPath = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'noConsoleRun.vbs')
#subprocess.Popen(r'wscript "'+vbsPath+'"')
```

**run.bat**
run.batは環境変数の設定をしてexeファイルを実行します。

```
SETLOCAL
SET PATH=%PATH%;..\..\samples\external\opencv\bin;..\..\bin;
test.exe
```

**noConsoleRun.vbs**
noConsoleRun.vbsは、.batファイルで表示される黒いコンソールウインドウを消すために使用します。

```
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
ws.run "cmd /c run.bat", vbhide
```

実際に、python_test.pyを実行すると、パターン1の.batファイル実行では次のようなエラーが出ます。

```
'test.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

パターン2の.vbsファイル実行ではエラーは出ないものの、何も実行されおらずコンソール以外のGUIも出てきません。

それぞれ、Pythonから実行せずに手動でrun.batやnoConsoleRun.vbsをダブルクリックすると普通に起動します。Pythonから実行した場合のみ、起動しません。

どうしたらPythonから実行できそうでしょうか？

Comment: その`python_tes.py`はどうやって実行しているかも書いておいてください。まあおそらくこちら [Pythonでカレントディレクトリをスクリプトのディレクトリに固定](https://qiita.com/moisutsu/items/46c7b29b1f68a83f6ec8) の記事内容を使ってPythonスクリプトの最初でその場所にカレントディレクトリを移動しておけば良いと思われます。

Comment: `python_tes.py`は、WinPythonという環境を使って`python "filePath"`で実行しています。run.batの方はそちらの記事内容で実行できましたが、vbsの方は実行できないようでした。

Comment: それならば同様のことですが、`run.bat`の先頭に`CD /D %~dp0`を挿入してバッチファイルの最初にバッチファイルのあるディレクトリに移動してみてください。

Comment: その方法で問題なく動作しました！ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントで解決したようなので、内容を回答として記述しておきます。

一応後から示したバッチファイルでの対策だけで動作しそうですが：

以下のように`run.bat`の先頭あるいは何処でも`test.exe`を実行する前に`CD /D %~dp0`を挿入してバッチファイルの存在するディレクトリをカレントディリクトリに変更します。

```
CD /D %~dp0
SETLOCAL
SET PATH=%PATH%;..\..\samples\external\opencv\bin;..\..\bin;
test.exe
```

もしかしたらPython, VBSどちらかで処理を起動出来ない？ことがあるかもしれないので、その場合は以下の記事を参考に、Pythonスクリプトの先頭でもスクリプトのあるディレクトリをカレントディレクトリに変更しておきます。
[Pythonでカレントディレクトリをスクリプトのディレクトリに固定](https://qiita.com/moisutsu/items/46c7b29b1f68a83f6ec8)

> ```
> import os
> os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
> ```